# Exporting Relationship "specifict job titles"

Tags: relationships, export

I need to export the "specific job title" field that is located in relationship.  I cannot find that field in any of the export drop-downs, nor any field with a language that even sounds like what I need. Situation is that we have "vacant" seats and will be using relationships and this title field for mailings.
Thank you...

Comment: Julie - so this is a Custom Field on a Relationship? If you are using Drupal you can probably easily get this data out via a drupal View. But that may not be any help to you.